# Как сгенерировать набор чисел, от мин до макс с указанной суммой?

Tags: алгоритм, генерация-случайных-данных

Нужно сгенерировать массив чисел, чтобы потом использовать их. Условия:

- Задается общая сумма `sum`
- Задается минимальное значение `min`
- Задается максимальное значение `max`
- Задается количество чисел `count` так, что сумма минимальных значений не превышала суммы `min * count < sum` и сумма максимальных была не меньше суммы `max * count > sum`
- Суммарное время всех чисел должно быть равно заданному `numbers.Sum() == sum`
- Числа должны быть случайными в интервале от `min` до `max`

Сигнатура функции:

```
int GenerateNumbers(int min, int max, int count, int sum)
```

---

Хотел сделать последовательность чисел по возрастанию, начиная с минимального значения, а затем перемешать массив. Но как вычислять значение на которое будем увеличивать так и не понял.

Подскажите, как составить алгоритм?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, неа, не дубликат.

Comment: Чем генерация случайный чисел отличается от генерации случайных пауз? Вообщем - ничем. `Случайное_число => Пауза` Или в виде функции `пауза(случайное_число())`

Comment: Ваша задача сводится к написанию ф-ции `случайное_число()`, а не к тому как написать случайные паузы (тем более если вы их так сильно ограничиваете - они уже не совсем случайные). Задачу вы поставили, но тут не решают задачи вместо вас. Сделайте ваши пункты самостоятельно, опубликуйте код сделаного.

Comment: @nick_n_a, несколько часов потратил пытаясь составить функцию. Увы, ничего не вышло и нечего показать, просто каша. А так с удовольствием выложил бы решение. Генерация пауз от чисел конечно же не отличается, просто так удобнее описать задачу.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а в чем разница между *Суммарное время всех пауз должно быть равно заданному* и *Сгенерировать массив чисел, сумма которых составит 1.*? Вон и ответ уже написали, суть которого та же, что и в моем ответе в предложенном дубликате. Таким же способом можно адаптировать и остальные ответы из того топика

Comment: Упустил еще условие с максимальным значением, поправил описание. Нужно чтобы числа генерировались в заданном диапазоне от `min` до `max`.

Comment: Информация про то что это паузы - совершенно излишняя

Comment: @АндрейNOP уже не дубликат, т.к. добавилось ограничение на макс значения чисел.

Comment: @Kromster, ага, это уже новая более сложная задача...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пусть общее время `T`, количество пауз `N`, минимальная пауза `t`.

Выделим на каждую паузу по `t`, останется `F=T-Nt`.

Теперь сгенерируем `N` случайных чисел `R[i]`
Посчитаем их сумму `S`
Нормализуем, чтобы общая сумма была `F`

```
 R[i] = R[i] * F / S
```

И добавим минимальные паузы

```
 R[i] = R[i] + t
```

---

С учётом максимума из [моего ответа на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324741/generation-of-random-numbers-with-an-average-in-c-sharp/52325229#52325229) (там не сумма, а среднее, легко модифицировать. Есть код на Python и ссылка на C#).
Замечу, что чем больше ограничений, тем менее равномерное распределение будет, но для многих практических целей это не страшно.

Сгенерировать случайные значения в диапазоне 0..1

Найти их среднее

Применить линейное преобразование

```
R[i] = NeededAverage - average + (r[i] - average) * 
        Math.Min((NeededMax - NeededAverage) / (1 - average), 
            (NeededAverage - NeededMin) / (average))
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. А можно еще как-нибудь скорректировать чтобы числа не превышали `max`, входили в диапазон от `min` до `max`?

Comment: Добавил с максимумом